# ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work in Asp.Net 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, validate-request

I have a form at which I use ckeditor. This form worked fine at Asp.Net 2.0 and 3.5 but now it doesn't work in Asp.Net 4+. I have ValidateRequest="false" directive. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's short article about rendering validation controls properly if anyone cares: [Error Validation in .NET 4](http://www.softcircuits.com/Blog/post/2010/06/04/Validation-Controls-Lost-Their-Red-Color.aspx)

Comment: can anyone please let me know what are the drawbacks of using ValidationRequest=false?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Found solution on the error page itself. Just needed to add requestValidationMode="2.0" in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

MSDN information: [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestValidationMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: that's awesome, but does anybody know of a way to set this per page?  Also how do I put this in web.config so that it would still work with .NET 2?

Comment: @MK: I don't think there is a page directive for this setting. You can not make it run on .net 2. I don't think that would be necessary. Because you can just build an web app targeting only one framework version. Just copy this line to .net 4 web.config which needs it...

Comment: But what has changed in validation for .net 4? Is there a way to do it without changing validation mode?

Comment: @Sly: You can find answer here: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

Comment: can anyone please let me know why in asp.net 4.0 application using requestValidationMode="2.0" is a good idea?

Comment: This worked for me. I could go without it within VS, but on a live server, I had to have this for the site to run as intended. Thank you, HasanG

Answer (score 105):

There is a way to turn the validation back to 2.0 for one page.  Just add the below code to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="XX/YY">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    ...
    the rest of your configuration
    ...

</configuration>
```

Comment: The location is any path, and is based on any node below the folder you specify in the tree.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer because it is not application wide rather narrow to the specific scope you define in the location path

Comment: The <location ..> declaration above should be placed inside the <configuration> declaration but not nested any further.

Comment: Per page setting doesn’t seem to be working for projects targeting .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Is there way to remove request validation for one action method ? I tried using attribute but it doesnt works

Answer (score 59):

I know this is an old question, but if you encounter this problem in MVC 3 then you can decorate your `ActionMethod` with `[ValidateInput(false)]` and just switch off request validation for a single `ActionMethod`, which is handy. And you don't need to make any changes to the `web.config` file, so you can still use the .NET 4 request validation everywhere else.

e.g.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionMethod Edit(int id, string value)
{
    // Do your own checking of value since it could contain XSS stuff!
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @RossCooper this is for asp.net MVC only

Answer (score 28):

This works without changing the validation mode.

You have to use a `System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated` helper from `System.Web.WebPages.dll`. It is going to return a `UnvalidatedRequestValues` object which allows to access the form and QueryString without validation.

For example,

```
var queryValue = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Unvalidated("MyQueryKey"));
```

Works for me for MVC3 and .NET 4.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to retrieve a queryString with this method? I keep getting 'Unvalidated is not a member of...' all objects I try to append it to. I think I might be missing an include

Comment: var queryValue = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Unvalidated("MyQueryKey"));

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer.  Maintains security and is extremely flexible since you can use it on a selective basis.

Comment: For Web Forms you have to replace entry in  QueryString collection to avoid validation error-see [A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client when sending html markup from jquery post call to asp.net page](//stackoverflow.com/a/44204652)

Answer (score 16):

Note that another approach is to keep with the 4.0 validation behaviour, but to define your own class that derives from `RequestValidator` and set:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationType="YourNamespace.YourValidator" />
```

(where `YourNamespace.YourValidator` is well, you should be able to guess...)

This way you keep the advantages of 4.0s behaviour (specifically, that the validation happens earlier in the processing), while also allowing the requests you need to let through, through.

Comment: This is good to know. But I still think the whole request validation feature of ASP.Net is misguided. The input itself is not the problem, it's what you *do* with it. It can be perfectly valid to accept SQL, HTML, or JavaScript code as input to your app, as long as you are encoding/escaping it properly before you output it or store it in your database.

Comment: @JordanRieger I partly agree. OOTB, it at least has the advantage of defaulting to secure (don't think things through and you get errors, rather than 0wned), but it's a bit of a nuisance and the pre-4.0 behaviour is very all-or-nothing.
There is something to the ability to have a validation layer that gets used before any other processing, as with a custom requestValidationType, but a lot of validation needs to be more tied in with other processing. In all I think it does more to protect people with bad habits from some (but not all) spl0its than to encourage good habits.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solved-ValidateRequest-false-not-working-in-Net-40-and-45-in-ASPNet.aspx

Summary:

1. If you want to set this at page level, set ValidateRequest="false" like this
   `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" %>`
2. You also need to modify httpRuntime to have requestValidationMode="2.0" or add it to `<system.web>` like this

> ```
> <system.web>
>     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="91200" executionTimeout="9000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
> </system.web>
> ```

That works for me in .NET 4.8

Answer (score -1):

After migration my application from dotnet framework 3.5 to 4.7, I get the same error.

Resolving it with adding requestValidationMode="2.0" to httpRuntime under system.web:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```