# ValidateRequest = False but in action it's still True and ignored that?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

i want disable **RequestValidation** on particular view in **ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RTM**. so i added some necessary to view Page directive section as below:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Path" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Path>" %>
```

but **RequestValidation** isn't Disabled! i also added **RequestValidation Attribute** to related action in controller as below:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Model instance)
{
    //Do here something
}
```

:') but **RequestValidation** isn't Disabled too!

in last try i set **RequestValidation** to false in **Web.config** file as below:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

**RequestValidation** still isn't turned off!

**Why? thank's in advance ;)**

Comment: How do you determine that ValidateRequest is not turned off? Also, please provide your .net framework version, asp.net and mvc versions.

Comment: because when i submit a form which one on field's have html tag i recieve an ValidationRequest exception. i'm using ASP.NET 4.0 and MVC 2.0

Comment: thank's for your link. but if i perform provided way to having this, all new feature's of this will be lose! there aren't any way to ignore validation for particular view/controller?

Comment: same question, some interesting alternatives not covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using asp.net 4.0 the validate request feature behavior has been changed from version 2.0. Check out the [breaking changes document here](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes/#0.1__Toc256770147). If this is the case you can resolve the problems by setting the request validation behavior back to the 2.0 in the web.config like this:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: This also fixes the problem for me. However I don't understand why. The breaking changes talk about extending validation to non-aspx-requests, however I'm only using it for a normal aspx page. Right now, it seems to me like validateRequest is simply broken in 4.0. If not, is there any proper way to doing it in 4.0 without essentially reverting to 2.0?

Comment: FYI: "The first change is to set the requestValidationMode attribute of the httpRuntime element to "2.0". This setting makes request validation occur later in the sequence of request processing events. The setting is required for applications that use ASP.NET 4 and later, because as of ASP.NET 4, request validation takes place earlier in the request life cycle than it did in previous versions of ASP.NET." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just add

[ValidateInput(false)]

in your controller function
but don't forget to encode the value to prevent harmful code

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public string Browse(string test)
    {
        string message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Value = " + test);
        return message;
    }
```