# A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, query-string, custom-error-handling

I'm using WebForm

I'm doing a Security Testing to my site but when I try to pass through url a QueryString like:

> '"-->netsparker(0x00286A) 
>   mysite/Error/PageNotFound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=%27%22--%3E%3C/style%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Enetsparker(0x0030C5)%3C/script%3E

I got Server Error in '/' Application.

> A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from
>   the client  A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (>).

I have in the web.config

```
<httpRuntime  enableVersionHeader="false"/>
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error/GeneralError.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/GeneralError.aspx" />    
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/GeneralError.aspx" />      
</customErrors>

    ..................

<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
```

Any idea how can I correct that?

Comment: That's a correct response from the server. However, you can disable request validation. Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4 Do read the MSDN page linked in that answer.

Comment: I follow the answer suggest but I continuing presenting the previous error and one aditional... Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885697/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client-w

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to violation of built in security rules in the ASP platform. These rules prevent injection and cross-site scripting attacks. If you are using MVC there is a handy AntiForgeryToken that can take care of this for you.

Please look into the post from Scot Hanselman

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: The link does not go anywhere, friend. "Error 404 page not found".

Comment: @Malky Corrected the link..

Comment: Thats not work for ASP.NET WebForm....