# Passing query string value from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my database table I have one column with the name ActionName.

This ActionName may contain action name with query string or without it.

I have a value like this: Customer?Start=New

In View I have actionlink which is using this model column.

When I click on this link, it gives error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client(?)
```

I tried using attribute [ValidateInput(false)] in action method and also [AllowHTML] in model, but still this error is shown.

How to safely pass query string parameter from database?

Comment: Can we see the code for the ActionLink and any relevant information from your controller action

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client when sending html markup from jquery post call to asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885697/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client-w)

Comment: Please see these articles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885697/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client-w AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009815/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client