# User control A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control and i am passing in a query string which .net seems to think is dangerous.. I have put in my web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>

<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

My user control is:

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Member.ascx.cs" Inherits="DOM.Umbraco.Web.usercontrols.Members" %>
```

But still no hope.. How can i get this to allow this query string?

Thanks
Dom

Comment: [Similar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885697/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client-w)

Comment: Thats a page not a control @gvashist

Comment: What is the query string you are trying to pass in?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable request validation with this web.config setting

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Take into account that no validation at all could lead to security problems. You need to replace the built in validation to some custom made code to clean up data from client.

If you want to restrict this setting only to the page where the user control is used, you can use this page directive

```
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: its a control not a page??

Comment: @Dom Adams: and what's the problem? My first approach disable request validation for the entire site.

Comment: Both do not work.. says The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. @claudioRedi

Comment: @Dom Adams: it seems you're making a mistake changing web.config. Error should include a detail about what's wrong on your web.config

Answer (score 0):

override the request validator and allow the characters you require.  Be careful, if the data is going to be re-displayed it will contain the original content, which could be dangerous. i.e. script tags

```
public class CustomRequestValidator : System.Web.Util.RequestValidator
{
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(HttpContext context, string value, RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey, out int validationFailureIndex)
    {
        validationFailureIndex = 0;

        if (requestValidationSource == RequestValidationSource.Form)
        {
            value = value.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
        }
        return base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
    }
}
```