# How to POST XML string in an ajax call to MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an XML string given below. I am trying to post it to MVC controller through Ajax call.And the MVC controller has a string parameter only. My ajax code is given below.But it is not being able to process the request. How can I send XML string to Controller

```
var textdata = "<bb>tt</bb><ff>rr</ff>";

         $.ajax({
             url: '/AppVersionProtocolMethod/Test',
             type: 'POST',
             data : { xmlData : textdata},
             success: function (datas) {

             }
         });
```

Thanks.
   -Soumya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client when sending html markup from jquery post call to asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885697/a-potentially-dangerous-request-querystring-value-was-detected-from-the-client-w)

Comment: You're making a POST - surely the data needs to go in the body of the request? Use `data: { xmlData: textdata }` instead

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `type` of you `ajax` call is set to `POST` while the way you are doing it in the `url` parameter using query string is done for `GET` requests.

The concatenated values are passed when we use `GET` request, you need to pass it using the `data` property then it will get passed to controller action as POST.

so change your code like below to make it work:

```
$.ajax({
         url: '/AppVersionProtocolMethod/Test',
         type: 'POST',
         data : { xmlData : textdata}
         success: function (datas) {

         }

     });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's true.But I tried this. Still it did not work.

Comment: can you be more descriptive, didn't work does not help to figure out what is wrong there?

Comment: I tried in the Controller action with an attribute called "ValidateInput(false)". And then it is able to take the XML string. But is that a good workaround or can you provide me with some better workarounds ?