# Request Validation - how and why is it disabled in SiteCore?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

We have a text box in sitecore that allows users to search for things.  This posts back to the server which goes off, does a search and returns some results (showing them on the screen).

When I input something dodgy, e.g. some markup I would expect to receive a .net exception along the lines of:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (q="<img src="http://www...").
```

As I understand it, [that has been default behaviour since v1.1 of ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation).  And then in v4.0 it remained the default [they just extended it to all requests](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) (not just web pages).

So the question is as follows:

```
1. how have sitecore disabled this?
2. what can I do to re-enable this globally (i.e. not on a per page basis)?
```

I note there is a section of the web.config that starts like this:

```
<!-- Continue to run Sitecore without script validations -->
<pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

Comment: I think your answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4

Comment: are you sure? Because I'm not trying to disable it; I'm trying to get the default behaviour back.  Also, in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\web.config
Line 18:        <pages validateRequest="true"/>

So this should be the root config which will be the default value if you don’t specify in your website’s web.config.

Comment: Well, if I understood well, .NET 4 changed that behavior. Yes, I assumed that you're building on top of v4. So, then, this should force v4 to behave like v2 in that respect: `<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>`. Then, you should be able to configure it the same way you used to with asp.net 2.0/3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own questions. Here are answers to your questions:

1. In Sitecore the default `web.config` comes with this set as 
   `<pages validateRequest="false" ... />`
2. To turn it on, set it to `true`

Also, you can take a look at [this blog post](http://aidandegraaf.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/sitecore-validate-request/) which indicates the `SuppressFormValidation` processor in the `PreprocessRequest` pipeline may be causing this issue you're having.

Here's the "offending" code that was identified:

```
namespace Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest
{
    public class SuppressFormValidation : PreprocessRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection form = args.Context.Request.Form;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestValidationException exception)
            {
                if (!args.Context.Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("/sitecore/shell/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Log.Error(exception.Message, exception, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The blog post has new code you can replace it with to only suppress validation in the Sitecore shell (the back-end GUI).

Comment: This has no effect.  I'll raise it to sitecore support.

Comment: That seems to be the right answer.  I've taken out that pipeline step and it works fine.  I'll look to re-enable it as that guy has done because SiteCore's own docs advise that taking it out altogether may break the content editor: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Configuring%20pages%20web,-d-,config%20section.aspx