# Can Set RequestValidationMode="2.0" page level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am developing a web application based on ASP.NET 4.0 and having some few pages with potential dangerous request(having markup codes).

So instead of setting RequestValidationMode="2.0" in web.config, can I set that property only for those few pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer hidden somewhere in msdn, hope this helps you too.. Better late then never
Try this,

```
<location path="test.aspx">
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
</location>
```

Reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding this error: **potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client.**

you can use page level property : `<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest="false" %>`

Comment: Yer.Already Used this directive ValidateRequest="false" in page. But it seems not working for .Net4.0 applications. So the suggestion was  use <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in web.config. And then it works fine. 

But when set this property it applies not only that page but for all HTTP requests.

Comment: have you gone through this link there similar issue is raised: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4

Comment: I went through that link and it is also mentioned use  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in web.config file.  

Actually I am looking for a way to add this property only for few pages(Either run-time code-behind or page-level). not for all HTTP requests. If any possibilities please update. Thanks.