# Error : potentially dangerous Request. how can able to allow the url containing a (&)

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my the url-

```
http://localhost:4566/PropertyMap/project/ackruti-gardenia-dahisar-&-beyond-mumbai
```

and I got error as-

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

**Stack Trace:**

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9673044
   System.Web.ValidateRequestExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +35
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Encode the ampersand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing parameters issue in javascript and c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155272/passing-parameters-issue-in-javascript-and-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8):

The ampersand (`&`) has special meaning in a URL, being used to separate elements within *Query String* and *Fragment* parts. This usage is forbidden by default because it's typical for hackers to probe around like this, trying to discover exploits.

To avoid this you need to use URL encoding on the path, so the ampersand is encoded to `%26`, making the final URL:

```
http://localhost:4566/PropertyMap/project/ackruti-gardenia-dahisar-%26-beyond-mumbai
```

Since you do not specify where the URL is constructed I cannot help you with how to encode it properly - implementation differs per language.

Comment: Not that I'm disagreeing with you, but wouldn't the _query_ actually start _after_ a question mark `?`? If an ampersand appears _before_ the question mark, does it still denote the query string? For example: `new Uri(@"http://localhost:4566/PropertyMap/project/ackruti-gardenia-dahisar-&-beyond-mumbai").Query` is blank, but the `LocalPath` still shows the full path. (the reported exceptions are probably how the request validation operates as a security measure) Only once you throw in a question mark in there does it start separating out the content.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've been working too hard today - fixed my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` method