# Allow Potentially dangerous content in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I trying to assign a string of the following type to a string variable in C#. I have looked at `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute but it disables validation for all the variables for the method it is used on. I just want it for one variable in the method.

```html
<A HREF="http://www.google.com">
```

But I'm getting the following exception when running this code.

`A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (mystr="<A HREF="http://www...").`

I'm assigning like

```cs
mystr = Request.QueryString["content"]
```

Kindly help we how to fix this. I have tried writing `[AllowHtml]` tag above the variable declaration. My string variable is a part of the model which is defined in Models.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster), I accept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365716) as my answer.

Comment: Casing and (lack of) spaces are important. You did write `[AllowHtml]`, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, thanks for confirming though, i'll correct it in the question.

Comment: While improperly titled and worded, that [question I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4) is _the_ canonical question for the question _"How can I get unvalidated variables in ASP.NET"_. It doesn't matter it isn't exactly the same question, your answer is in there.

Comment: Anyone searching for the same solution might not find the answer in that question. I request you to kindly unmark my question as duplicate.

Comment: Duplicates serve that exact purpose. An alternative question with the same problem and answers is [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client).