# How to get the innerHTML inside a asp div dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have `div` control which runs on server

```
<div id="report" runat="server" ></div>
```

I'm appending some content to the above `div` using `jquery` at run time. Now i want to access the innerHtml of the above div.

example:

```
<div id="report" runat="server" >
  <div class="someclass">some Text1</div>
  <div class="someclass">some Text2</div>
  <div class="someclass">some Text3</div>
</div>
```

expected output is(following HTML in a string format):

```
  <div class="someclass">some Text1</div>
  <div class="someclass">some Text2</div>
  <div class="someclass">some Text3</div>
```

so far i tried the following two methods but no luck

```
ContentPlaceHolder myContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("contentPlaceHolder");
Control cc= myContent.FindControl("report");
```

and

```
string HTMLString=report.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

Form input elements inside a form element posted to server.

All other content is static and not posted to server. 
It's fundamental rule of HTTP, you can see details [from here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format).
So you cannot get the `report.InnerHtml`.

You have two option, while preparing your div's content, write the same content inside a hidden field. And at server side get the hidden field's value.

```
<input type="hidden"  id="hdnDivContents" runat="server">
```

and set the value using jquery or javascript.

```
$('#<% hdnDivContents.ClientID %>').val($("#<% report.ClientID %>").val());
```

and get the value in code behind

```
string HTMLString=hdnDivContents.Value;
```

Or make an AJAX call while preparing your content to get it at server side.

Comment: i have tried the hidden field solution but ended with run time exception(`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$hdnDivContents="
<div class='reportHe...").`

Comment: You need to allow this for your page. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4)

Comment: same exception after doing the changes as you suggested