# Can't switch of "validation input" and getting error message .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Tried:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
    public class MatchesController : ApiController
```

In web.config I have:

```
<httpRuntime  requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<pages validateRequest="false"/>
```

But still I am getting an error while using put method on address
http://localhost:51770/servers/62.210.26.98-1337/matches/2017-01-22T15:17:00Z

**Error**:
a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client (:)

Apparently, it has problem with ":", how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [colon(:) in url causes error in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727565/colon-in-url-causes-error-in-asp-net)

Comment: take a look at the answer that I have marked as a possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If Validate input  not works may you try to use AllowHtml attirbute on your model.
as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc-validateinput-or-allowhtml)

> For ASP.NET MVC 3 applications, when you need to post HTML back to
>   your model, don’t use ValidateInput(false) to turn off Request
>   Validation. Simply add [AllowHtml] to your model property, like so:

```
public class BlogEntry {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    [AllowHtml] 
    public string BlogText {get;set;}
 }
```

**UPDATE:**
For web api request my you try like this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: It is not a property, so I can not use [AllowHttml]

Comment: I am trying to make API actually, not a web page

Comment: Could you try like requestPathInvalidCharacters="" and  <pages validateRequest="false" /> in config file.