# Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' thrown in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

Within my ASP.NET web app I use ELMAH for error handling and I'm seeing a lot of these errors in my log:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
    at System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I can't seem to reproduce them in dev and can't figure out what might be causing it. Anyone have any ideas? A possible hack attempt causing ASP.NET to throw this weird exception?

Comment: it can be anything.. since [System.Web.HttpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx) covers all web related problem in IIS.. (or rather, ASP). any clue from the IIS logs itself? perhaps you ran into HTTP Error 500 or something..

Comment: I believe this is the same error from this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4